# Assign the results of a for each loops with if statement to variables

Tags: powershell, csv, variables

I have a script which imports a CSV file, and runs a number of `foreach` loops to look for certain conditions and when found outputs some of the contents of the rows to the console in a format I specify.  This works fine but instead of outputting it to the console, I want to redirect the output to new variables (1 variable per `foreach` loop).

I want to do this because certain loops I will use to create files, others I will use in for emails, and then some I would want to output to the console. In my example, I basically want to eliminate my `Write-Host` commands and write then to variables, but no matter what I try it doesn't work so I'm missing something.

```
function check-csv {
    $IN_CSV = C:\Temp\IN_CSV.csv
    $CSV = Import-Csv $IN_CSV | foreach {
        ## Need the results of this to be $VAR1 
        if ($_.Status -match "Cancelled" ) {
            Write-Host  $_.Status, $_.Ticket
        }
        $_
    } | foreach {
        ## Need the results of this to be $VAR2
        if ($_.Owner -match "Jonny Appleseed" ) {
            Write-Host  $_.Status, $_.Ticket $_.Owner
        }
        $_
    } | foreach {
        ## Need the results of this to be $VAR3
        if ($_.Priority -match "none" ) {
            Write-Host $_.Status, $_.Ticket $_.Priority 
        }
        $_
    } 

    # The individual variables will be used for different purposes.  
    #Examples (3 use case I would have)

    #Just output to concole
    Write-Host "Cancellation Warnings" 
    Write-Host $VAR1

    Write-Host "Owned by Jonny Appleseed" 
    Write-Host $VAR2

    #Use a variable in the body of an email
    Send-MailMessage -Subject "Cancellation Warnings" -Body $VAR1

    #Create and append to a CSV file
    $VAR3 | Export-Csv -path C:\Temp\VAR3.csv
```

Comment: Avoid that bizarro pipelineing and everything will be a lot easier. `$Var1 = $CSV | Where-Object { $_.Status -match "Cancelled" }` and `$Var2 = $CSV | Where-Object { $_.Owner -match 'Johnny.*' }` and such.

Comment: This worked after I then converted it into an array, thank you!  Maybe there was a better way of doing it that I am not aware if but as written I was not able to pull out the specific Data that I needed ($_.Status, $_.Ticket as an example).